# Vim-LaTeX Installation using Pathogen

Tags: vim, plugins, latex, pathogen

experts,

I am trying to install Vim-LaTeX in Gvim using Pathogen. I am an intermediate user of Vim and have installed many many plugins but this plugin is giving me much grief. I have spent enough time for me not to quit!!

I got the folder from this website. [Vim-Latex installation](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-latex/files/). And I copied the folder in my `~/vimfiles/bundle/` folder. I also have added the specified settings in my `_vimrc` file. ([vim-latex settings](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html)).

But when I am relaunching Gvim, it does not show all the new menus as shown below.

Please help. I can see all other default menus (like File, Edit, Tools, Syntax, Buffers etc). Is this plugin not supposed to work with Pathogen (by simply copying it in `bundle` folder)?
[image]

Comment: Do you start Vim with a `*.tex` file?

Comment: Yes. I did. I opened an existing .tex file, it did not show up all the menus. Then I created a new one from Gvim.

Comment: This is very late, but did you get this to work? I guess you had already put something like `execute pathogen#infect('bundle/{}', '~/vimfiles/bundle/{}')` into your ~/.vimrc?